# Which release would fit my Dell Inspiron N4030?

Tags: dell, system-requirements

I wish to switch from Windows 7 to Ubuntu, and I'm trying to figure which (LTS) release should I use, whether to use the newest (16.04), an older one or one of the light-weight flavours (my computer is a bit old - bought on october 2010). My specs are:

- Dell Inspiron N4030
- Intel Core i3-350M, 2.26GHz
- 3GB RAM
- ATI Radeon HD530 512MB
- Currently running Windows 7 64-bit

My usage is quite standard - internet, photos, videos, word-processing (mainly using LyX for LaTeX).

Thanks.

Comment: @edwinksl I have read the answers there, and they are a bit too general. Although it seems that my computer fits the official system requirements, I would prefer a more focused opinion regarding my specific specs. Maybe even someone with experience with this computer,,,

Comment: Your question is not that specific to begin with, so I wouldn't expect super specific answers if I were you. Given your current question, the best we can do is to see if your hardware specs meet the minimum requirements for Ubuntu and its various flavors. Anything more specific depends on your own idiosyncratic software usage patterns and preferences for customizability, speed, etc., all of which you haven't specified in your question.

Comment: "Old" isn't 2010. That's new in the scope of computers Ubuntu can run on.

Comment: @Zacharee1 good to know, I was under the impression that 6 years is already considered "old" these days...

Comment: @UrBen-Ari-Tishler for Windows, maybe, and for Mac it's beyond ancient, but Linux is very good at running on old hardware.

Comment: @UrBen-Ari-Tishler Keep in mind you can try out Ubuntu before installing it, by booting from a live CD/USB.

Answer (score 0):

The latest LTS (Long Term Support) version would suit you just fine.  Go with the 32x version.  You can download it from the main download page.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

If it's too slow, try LXDE.
`sudo apt-get install lxde-desktop`

LXDE and openbox will then be available on the login screen.  (After you log out, not lock.)

Openbox is fast, LXDE is easy.

Comment: Thanks. Why 32x version and not 64 if my computer is currently on 64?

Comment: As it was explained to me, 32x is better at managing memory on systems with less than 4gb.  It seems work with less bugginess on some of my old computers.

Comment: @Mrlong2 if you have a 64-bit system, there's not much reason to use a 32-bit OS. 3GB is over the recommended amount of RAM for 64-bit Ubuntu anyway, and it would work below that recommendation as well (2GB). I think what you heard may have come from the fact that 64-bit can just support over 4GB.

Comment: I would go with the 64-bit version of Ubuntu if your system is a 64-bit there's no reason to install the 32-bit

Answer (score 0):

With the specs you provided I think a lighter distribution would do well  on that machine. Try [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/), it is a great light weight desktop environment that requires very little resources

If you would also like to read what the requirements are to run Ubuntu 16.04, you can start here: [Ubuntu installation requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) in most cases it's better to have more Ram then what's required as Ubuntu is developed is also consumes more of our system system resources

I would also recommend sticking with the LTS releases because they are supported for a number of years, here is a chart that will give you a break down on what to expect with LTS releases, [LTS, Long Term Support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS)